# How to use two different classes in one main GTK app

Tags: c++, clips, gtkmm3

I'm trying to make GTK frontend and CLIPS backend work together in sync. The structure of my app is as follows:

1. CLIPSWindow class contains the GUI code of the app.
2. GTKClips contains the c++ wrappers around the common CLIPS constructs.
3. Main app instantiates a design from Glade GUI designer and runs it using `Gtk::kit`

[here](https://github.com/ankghost0912/GTKClips) is a link to my github repo. The files of importance are `GTKClips.{h,cpp}`, `clipswindow.{h,cpp}` and `main_app.cpp`.

To put the question more clearly: How do I instantiate a member of `GTKClips` class so that it can be used by `clipswindow` class to send and receive data. Should I pass it as a parameter to the constructor of `clipswindow` and then use it in the class or something else?

Comment: Can you point me to the original question?

Comment: The CLIPS files have .c extensions. Are you using the appropriate option for compiling them as C++ files?

Comment: Since the C functions are wrapped around C++ wrappers, I didn't include that option. I'm trying to get the GtkCLIPS(my backend) to talk to the GTKWindow subclass. Since you're one of the core devs of CLIPS, can I contact you?

Comment: GtkCLIPS.cpp includes GtkCLIPS.h which includes clips.h. Unless you wrap the clips.h include within an extern "C" block, the names will be mangled during the C++ file compilation and the linker will not be able to find the functions if the corresponding source file is compiled as C code. If you're mixing C++ code with code that's both valid C and C++ code, the simplest solution is to compile everything as C++. Support emails for CLIPS are at http://www.clipsrules.net/?q=Support.